# pdfContentBlob "is not a function" error Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

When using this script,

```
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1n-k8aqgAPRZGoF1aOm-Yg3K8gtVHbQfA");
const pdfContentBlob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob)().setName(lastName + ', ' + ponum)();
```

it works, but I get the error "TypeError: pdfFolder.createFile(...) is not a function."

I've tried all combinations of () but it always errs out. What do I need to change?

Comment: Remove all empty `()`

Comment: This is a simple syntax error, I recommend you do some studying on reading JS error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1n-k8aqgAPRZGoF1aOm-Yg3K8gtVHbQfA");
const pdfContentBlob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(lastName + ', ' + ponum);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was literally the first JS script I ever wrote so yea, more studying!

Comment: BTW not to be picky but server side Javascript for google is called Google Apps Script although most JavaScript also works server side.  But Javascript is really mostly a client side language because it's designed to work in the browsers.